# Transferring File Properties

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, amazon-cloud-drive

I found an answer here (from 7/2012) to a question via Google. However, I have a follow-up question. The question was about losing file properties when transferring files to a new location. The error says 'Are you sure you want to move this file to a new location without the file properties?' It answered the 'why' but not a solution.

I am moving folders downloaded from my Amazon Drive in preparation for the upcoming storage limits, & am moving them to an external drive. I still have 1204 folders to move. Is there a way to get around having to click ok for every folder as the error comes up?

Comment: What filesystem type is your external drive? A website I've just read seems to think you shouldn't get this dialog if the drive is NTFS as it relates to file properties that non-NTFS simply can't store (hence the prompt)...?

Comment: It is NTFS. It is a 3T. NAS.